# Prioritize Chats over "Assigned", but not "Opened" Cases in Omni-Channel

Tags: apex, liveagent, service-cloud-console, omnichannel

I am using Salesforce Omni-channel. I am using it for Cases and Chat. When I set my status to "Available - Chat", the expectation is that I can receive Cases and Chats. Right now, as soon as agents log in, they are flooded with cases in the queue. What this is preventing is the ability for our agents to accept chats when they come in.

**We want to prioritize chats**, but if agents have so many pending cases (Assigned agent work of cases), it is not allowing the chats to hit their queue because they are "At Capacity".

As soon as a chat comes in I want the cases that are **assigned** agent work to be moved out of my name in favor of the chats. How can I make this happen?

Below is the presence status that makes the agent available for both Chat and Cases.

[image]

Despite me being available for chat, which is what I'd like to prioritize, only the cases that are already in my omni-potential workload are showing up.

[image]

Below are my routing configurations and as you can see, chat has the highest routing priority.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot you provided, I see you have the presence status ‘Available - Chat’, which includes the case queue too. As you want to prioritize chats, you could have 2 different presence statuses, where one is blended Case and Chat, and the other solely chat to solve your scenario.

Also, it is on Salesforce's roadmap(GA in Winter'24- Safe Harbour) to have "Interruptible Capacity" to meet this requirement, wherein you can mark cases to be able to be interrupted by other work (e.g. Chats)

Comment: Can we get an article for this update one please?